# Weird insertion from Vim on mouse click

Tags: vim, putty

I'm using putty (on windows 7) to connect to shell and Vim as editor. I also have mouse=a option enabled in Vim, but I get some strange behavior (such as random insertions of characters and/or linebreaks) when I click to the right side of the Vim window (let's say it's like 70%+ of the screen width area where it gets weird). I'm slowly getting used to such behavior, but I'd really like to know if I could somehow fix this.

Comment: How big is your window, in terms of character cells? The original xterm mouse protocol as implemented by PuTTY only supports mouse coordinates up to 223.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware of such limitations. Window size is measured in rows and columns in PuTTY, so after few tries I figured out 95 columns is perfect match for xterm mouse protocol. Do you mind leaving your solution as answer so I could mark it as best one? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PuTTY sends mouse events using an xterm protocol that dates back all the way to X10 in the mid-eighties. This encodes the mouse coordinates with a single byte each for row and column, whereby 32 (the ASCII code for a space character) is added. This allows for coordinates up to 223 (which is 255 - 32).

Unfortunately that encoding does not adhere to the applicable standards for terminal control sequences, and the range can effectively be further restricted to 95 (i.e. 127 - 32) if applications don't make special allowances for it. In particular, if an application performs UTF-8 decoding before control sequence parsing, mouse coordinates beyond 95 just end up being treated as invalid UTF-8.

During the past year, several attempts have been made to address this issue in xterm. The best one of those is the so-called SGR 1006 mode added in [patch #277](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_277), which uses a standard-compliant control sequence with unlimited coordinates. Support for this will slowly permeate to other terminal emulators and applications.

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed in [Vim 7.3.632](ftp://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/patches/7.3/7.3.632). See `:h sgr-mouse`. Or just put this in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
set ttymouse=sgr
```

If you want to be compatible with versions that don't have `mouse_sgr` compiled in, use:

```
if has("mouse_sgr")
    set ttymouse=sgr
else
    set ttymouse=xterm2
end
```

To see if your version of Vim has `mouse_sgr`, run `vim --version` from the command-line, or in Vim, enter `:version`, and look for `+mouse_sgr`.